# Like button performing two functions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, interface

I wonder if there is a way to create a facebook like button that clicks when you short a particular post on face book and record in my database oo his name from the user, or by clicking the button like accomplishes two functions, one on facebook and one in my database.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook [Like button plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) which lets you give it a Javascript callback. You can link this callback to your database using AJAX.

Edit:

You asked for an example.

First you write a javascript function in the global scope. This is the function that you want to do stuff when somebody clicks the like button. Say you declared it like this:

```
function logFacebookLike(response) {
    // AJAX to log to database
}
```

Now, at some point after you've loaded the button, you subscribe to the Facebook edge.create event and give it your callback. Facebook will run your function and pass in some data (as the response variable). You can subscribe to the event like this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', logFacebookLike);
```

That's it. You can learn more in the [Facebook Javascript Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). If you wanted an example of the AJAX, then you need to create a different question with a more specific context.

Comment: hello you have an example? I do not know how to call a callback function

Comment: The point of callbacks is that the application you give them to calls them: you just have to give the application the callback.

On Facebook, you create a callback function, say `function my_callback()`, and you then hand it off to facebook by registering for the edge.create event: `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', my_callback);`  You can find more [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class or id to your facebook like button using jquery and using  a click function as josaphatv mentioned trigger a callback function to your database using AJAX to save the information you needed.